# R - compare two string variables and derive a third variable based on the comparison

Tags: r

Let's say you have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Var1 Var2
A    A  
B    B  
A    B  
B    A
```

I'm trying to make a variable `Var3` that would be `1` if `Var1` and `Var2` are equal and `0` if they are not. So, the dataframe should look like this:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
A    A    1
B    B    1
A    B    0
B    A    0
```

I'm using the following code:

```
data %<>%
  mutate_if(vars(Var1) == vars(Var2), Var3 = 1) %>% 
  mutate_if(vars(Var1) != vars(Var2), Var3 = 0)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in vars(Var1) == vars(Var2) : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
```

What am I supposed to do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dplyr I would use case_when, its helpfull when you have multiple conditions.

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = c("A","B","A","B"),
                 Var2 = c("A","B","B","A"))

df %>%
  mutate(Var3 = case_when(Var1 == Var2 ~ 1,
                          Var1 != Var2 ~ 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to make it too complicated you can directly do :

```
as.integer(df$Var1 == df$Var2)
#Or even shorter
#+(df$Var1 == df$Var2)
#[1] 1 1 0 0
```

which is faster way than doing with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(df$Var1 == df$Var2, 1, 0)
```